# Magento lack of page content after update

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

So after updating shop version from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.2 one of the products(not all) started missing page content, like I cannot see the description, add to basket etc. It went from looking like this:
[image]

To looking like that:

[image]

My only guess it has simething to do with .html forms, but it's my guess. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the server error, maybe inside /var/log/apache/error.log or /var/log/nginx.error
Probably a patch broke some php functionality

Answer (score 0):

To see the error in that page go to index.php and uncomment this line

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

If it's a memory limit error either edit your php ini or add these to index.php

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
```